# Why does as.matrix add extra spaces when converting numeric to character?

Tags: r

If you use apply over rows on a data.frame with character and numeric columns, apply uses as.matrix internally to convert the data.frame to only characters. But if the numeric column consists of numbers of different lengths, as.matrix adds spaces to match the highest/"longest" number.

An example:

```
df <- data.frame(id1=c(rep("a",3)),id2=c(100,90,8), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
df
##   id1 id2
## 1   a 100
## 2   a  90
## 3   a   8
as.matrix(df)
##      id1 id2  
## [1,] "a" "100"
## [2,] "a" " 90"
## [3,] "a" "  8"
```

I would have expected the result to be:

```
     id1 id2  
[1,] "a" "100"
[2,] "a" "90"
[3,] "a" "8"
```

Why the extra spaces?

They can create unexpected results when using apply on a data.frame:

```
myfunc <- function(row){
  paste(row[1], row[2], sep = "")
}
> apply(df, 1, myfunc)
[1] "a100" "a 90" "a  8"
>
```

While looping gives the expected result.

```
> for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  print(myfunc(df[i,]))
}
[1] "a100"
[1] "a90"
[1] "a8"
```

and

```
> paste(df[,1], df[,2], sep = "")
[1] "a100" "a90"  "a8"
```

Are there any situations where the extra spaces that are added with as.matrix is useful?

Comment: Thanks for answers. I now have a better understanding of as.matrix and format and learned a few new tricks. I've updated my question, since I was also looking for a rationale behind the spaces, as they just seem to get in the way.

Comment: I ran into this exact issue when using `apply` which calls `as.matrix` internally.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is because of the way non-numeric data are converted in the `as.matrix.data.frame` method. There is a simple work-around, shown below.

### Details

`?as.matrix` notes that conversion is done via `format()`, and it is here that the additional spaces are added. Specifically, `?as.matrix` has this in the **Details** section:

```
 ‘as.matrix’ is a generic function.  The method for data frames
 will return a character matrix if there is only atomic columns and
 any non-(numeric/logical/complex) column, applying ‘as.vector’ to
 factors and ‘format’ to other non-character columns.  Otherwise,
 the usual coercion hierarchy (logical < integer < double <
 complex) will be used, e.g., all-logical data frames will be
 coerced to a logical matrix, mixed logical-integer will give a
 integer matrix, etc.
```

`?format` also notes that

> Character strings are padded with blanks to the display width of the widest.

Consider this example which illustrates the behaviour

```
> format(df[,2])
[1] "100" " 90" "  8"
> nchar(format(df[,2]))
[1] 3 3 3
```

`format` doesn't *have* to work this way as it has `trim`:

```
trim: logical; if ‘FALSE’, logical, numeric and complex values are
      right-justified to a common width: if ‘TRUE’ the leading
      blanks for justification are suppressed.
```

e.g.

```
> format(df[,2], trim = TRUE)
[1] "100" "90"  "8"
```

but there is no way to pass this argument along to the `as.matrix.data.frame` method.

### Workaround

A way to work around this is to apply `format()` yourself, manually, via `sapply`. There you can pass in `trim = TRUE`

```
> sapply(df, format, trim = TRUE)
     id1 id2  
[1,] "a" "100"
[2,] "a" "90" 
[3,] "a" "8"
```

or, using `vapply` we can state what we expect to be returned (here character vectors of length 3 [`nrow(df)`]):

```
> vapply(df, format, FUN.VALUE = character(nrow(df)), trim = TRUE)
     id1 id2  
[1,] "a" "100"
[2,] "a" "90" 
[3,] "a" "8"
```

Comment: Presumably, the rationale here is that using `format` is simpler than doing different things for character and date columns, right?

Comment: @joran `format` has many methods for different classes out-of-the-box. Hence it *is* doing something different for numeric and Date objects (due to method dispatch on `format`). Once it is determined that there are non-numeric data, the only solution is to produce a character matrix and `format` is the easiest way to do that.

Comment: Would it not be possible to simply to change `format(xj)` to `format(xj,...)` in `as.matrix.data.frame`? This would allow us to pass `trim=TRUE` to `format`.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I guess what I meant is that I'm not clear on why `format` would be preferred over `as.character` (which also has tons of methods out of the box).

Comment: @Joran - I speculate that this is that `format` has far more methods in general, and possibly backwards compatibility with S (S-PLU)?

Comment: @nograpes Not without editing it in the sources and compiling yourself, or updating the method at the start of every sessions with an suitably located `assignInNamespace` call.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Right. I was thinking that this would be a nice feature addition in base. Maybe I'll ask for it on the mailing list.

Comment: @nograpes Oh right - well yes, that would be the way to go. Won't happen for a while though, even if someone on R Core bites, as they are in freeze for R 3.0.0. Make sure you provide a good use-case when you do suggest. Perhaps sound out on R-Devel first as there may be unintended side effects of `...` passing.

Answer (score 9):

It does seem a little strange. In the manual (`?as.matrix`) it explains that `format` is called for the conversion to a character matrix:

> The method for data frames will return a character matrix if there is
>   only atomic columns and any non-(numeric/logical/complex) column,
>   applying as.vector to factors and *format* to other non-character
>   columns.

And you can see that if you call `format` directly, it does what `as.matrix` does:

```
format(df$id2)
[1] "100" " 90" "  8"
```

What you need to do is pass the `trim` arugment:

```
format(df$id2,trim=TRUE)
[1] "100" "90"  "8"
```

But, unfortunately, the `as.matrix.data.frame` function doesn't allow you to do that.

```
else if (non.numeric) {
    for (j in pseq) {
        if (is.character(X[[j]])) 
            next
        xj <- X[[j]]
        miss <- is.na(xj)
        xj <- if (length(levels(xj))) 
            as.vector(xj)
        else format(xj) # This could have ... as an argument
        # else format(xj,...)
        is.na(xj) <- miss
        X[[j]] <- xj
    }
}
```

So, you could modify `as.data.frame.matrix`. I think it would be a nice feature addition, however, to include this in base.

But, a quick solution would be to simply:

```
as.matrix(data.frame(lapply(df,as.character)))
     id1 id2  
[1,] "a" "100"
[2,] "a" "90" 
[3,] "a" "8"  
# As mentioned in the comments, this also works:
sapply(df,as.character)
```

Comment: +1 for the work-around. Note it can be simplified to `sapply(df, format, trim = TRUE)` given the nature of the simplifications that `sapply` does. To be extra certain, you could use `vapply` instead and specify the type of returned objects.

Comment: the `as.matrix()` is fully redundant here - `sapply` is returning a matrix. Try: `class(sapply(df,as.character))`

Answer (score 6):

`as.matrix` calls `format` internally:

```
 > format(df$id2)
[1] "100" " 90" "  8"
```

That's where the extra spaces come from. `format` has an extra argument `trim` to remove those:

```
> format(df$id2, trim = TRUE)
[1] "100" "90"  "8"
```

However you cannot supply this argument to `as.matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behaviour is already explained in previous answers, but I'd like to offer another way of circumventing this:

```
df <- data.frame(id1=c(rep("a",3)),id2=c(100,90,8), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
do.call(cbind,df)
     id1 id2  
[1,] "a" "100"
[2,] "a" "90" 
[3,] "a" "8"
```

Note that if using `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`, this doesn't work as factor levels are converted to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution: trimWhiteSpace(x) (from limma R pckg) also does the job if you don't mind downloading the package.

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("limma")
library(limma)
df <- data.frame(id1=c(rep("a",3)),id2=c(100,90,8), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
as.matrix(df)
 id1 id2  
[1,] "a" "100"
[2,] "a" " 90"
[3,] "a" "  8"

trimWhiteSpace(as.matrix(df))
 id1 id2  enter code here
[1,] "a" "100"
[2,] "a" "90" 
[3,] "a" "8"
```