# r apply function pads spaces to match character lengths

Tags: r, dataframe, whitespace, apply

I am using apply to generate strings from a data frame.

For example:

```
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(1:3), b=c(9:11))
apply(df2, 1, function(row) paste0("hello", row['a']))
apply(df2, 1, function(row) paste0("hello", row['b']))
```

works as I would expect and generates

```
[1] "hello1" "hello2" "hello3"
[1] "hello9" "hello10" "hello11"
```

However, if I have

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1:3), b=c(9:11), c=c("1", "2", "3"))
apply(df, 1, function(row) paste0("hello", row['a']))
apply(df, 1, function(row) paste0("hello", row['b']))
```

the output is

```
[1] "hello1" "hello2" "hello3"
[1] "hello 9" "hello10" "hello11"
```

Can any one please explain why I get a padded space to make all the strings the same length in the second case? I can work around the problem using gsub, but I would like to have a better understanding of why this happens

Comment: take a look at what `as.matrix(df)` does (`apply` uses `as.matrix`) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618527/why-does-as-matrix-add-extra-spaces-when-converting-numeric-to-character => fix with `apply(do.call(cbind, df), 1, function(row) { (str(row['b'])); paste0("hello", row['b']) })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `apply` transforms your `data.frame` in a `matrix`. See what happens when you coerce `df` to matrix:

```
 as.matrix(df)
     a   b    c  
[1,] "1" " 9" "1"
[2,] "2" "10" "2"
[3,] "3" "11" "3"
```

Notice that it coerced to a character matrix and it included the extra space on the `" 9"`.

Comment: isn't that just what the comment said to do?

Comment: @hrbrmstr there was no comment when I started writing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need apply function:

```
 paste0("hello", df[["a"]])
[1] "hello1" "hello2" "hello3"

paste0("hello", df[["b"]])
[1] "hello9"  "hello10" "hello11"
```