# Apply `dplyr::rowwise` in all variables

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(4, runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  y = sample(1:3, 30, replace = TRUE)
)
```

The follow function work:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_1 %>% 
  select(-y) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(var = sum(c(x.1, x.3)))
```

But, the follows functions (for all variables) dooesn't work:

**with `.`:**

```
df_1 %>% 
  select(-y) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(var = sum(.))
```

**with `select_if`:**

```
df_1 %>% 
  select(-y) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(var = sum(select_if(., is.numeric)))
```

The both methods return:

```
Source: local data frame [30 x 5]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 30 x 5
     x.1   x.2   x.3   x.4   var
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  32.7  42.7  50.1  20.8 7091.
 2  75.9  71.3  83.6  77.6 7091.
 3  49.6  28.7  97.0  59.7 7091.
 4  47.4  96.1  31.9  79.7 7091.
 5  54.2  47.1  81.7  41.6 7091.
 6  27.9  58.1  97.4  25.9 7091.
 7  61.8  78.3  52.6  67.7 7091.
 8  85.4  51.3  38.8  82.0 7091.
 9  27.9  72.6  68.9  25.2 7091.
10  87.2  42.1  27.6  73.9 7091.
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Where `7091` is a incorrect sum.

How adjustment this functions?

Comment: You can use `rowSums`: `df_1 %>% 
  mutate(var = rowSums(select(., starts_with('x.'))))`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, I need use `rowwise`.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396267/dplyr-rowwise-sum-and-other-functions-like-max) answer your question?

Comment: Doesn't work. I need sum for each case (line) for **all** variables.

Comment: Can be done using `purrr` package: `df_1 %>% select(-y) %>% mutate(var = pmap(., lift(sum)))`

Comment: And `mean` or `sd`?

Comment: @GiovaniNeves: It's the same thing for `mean` and `sd`. Just use a different domain lifter: `df_1 %>% select(-y) %>% mutate( var = pmap(., lift_vd(mean)) )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using [`purrr::pmap`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html), which passes a list of arguments to a function that accepts "dots". Since most functions like `mean`, `sd`, etc. work with vectors, you need to pair the call with a [domain lifter](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/lift.html):

```
df_1 %>% select(-y) %>% mutate( var = pmap(., lift_vd(mean)) )
#         x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4      var
# 1  70.12072 62.99024 54.00672 86.81358 68.48282
# 2  49.40462 47.00752 21.99248 78.87789 49.32063

df_1 %>% select(-y) %>% mutate( var = pmap(., lift_vd(sd)) )
#         x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4      var
# 1  70.12072 62.99024 54.00672 86.81358 13.88555
# 2  49.40462 47.00752 21.99248 78.87789 23.27958
```

The function `sum` accepts dots directly, so you don't need to lift its domain:

```
df_1 %>% select(-y) %>% mutate( var = pmap(., sum) )
#         x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4      var
# 1  70.12072 62.99024 54.00672 86.81358 273.9313
# 2  49.40462 47.00752 21.99248 78.87789 197.2825
```

Everything conforms to the standard `dplyr` data processing, so all three can be combined as separate arguments to `mutate`:

```
df_1 %>% select(-y) %>% 
  mutate( v1 = pmap(., lift_vd(mean)),
          v2 = pmap(., lift_vd(sd)),
          v3 = pmap(., sum) )
#         x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4       v1       v2       v3
# 1  70.12072 62.99024 54.00672 86.81358 68.48282 13.88555 273.9313
# 2  49.40462 47.00752 21.99248 78.87789 49.32063 23.27958 197.2825
```

Comment: Thanks. But, and for more than function? Example, for `mean`, `sd` and `var` (3 new columns)? See: `mutate(var = pmap(., lift_vd(mean, sd, var)))` doesn't work.

Comment: @GiovaniNeves: Just combine those inside `mutate` like you would normally. See the edit above.

Comment: Great solution! Thanks, @Artem Sokolov!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is tricky because the scoped variants of mutate (`mutate_at`, `mutate_all`, `mutate_if`) are generally aimed at executing a function on a specific column, instead of creating an operation that uses all columns.

The simplest solution I can come up with basically amounts to creating a vector (`cols`) that is then used to execute the summary operation:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(4, runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  y = sample(1:3, 30, replace = TRUE)
)

# create vector of columns to operate on
cols <- names(df_1)
cols <- cols[map_lgl(df_1, is.numeric)]
cols <- cols[! cols %in% c("y")]

cols
#> [1] "x.1" "x.2" "x.3" "x.4"

df_1 %>% 
  select(-y) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    var = sum(!!!map(cols, as.name), na.rm = TRUE)
  )
#> Source: local data frame [30 x 5]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 30 x 5
#>      x.1   x.2   x.3   x.4   var
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  46.1  28.9  28.9  50.7  155.
#>  2  26.8  68.0  67.1  26.5  188.
#>  3  35.2  63.8  62.5  28.5  190.
#>  4  31.3  44.9  67.3  68.2  212.
#>  5  52.6  23.9  83.2  43.4  203.
#>  6  55.7  92.8  86.3  57.2  292.
#>  7  56.9  50.0  77.6  25.6  210.
#>  8  95.0  82.6  86.1  22.7  286.
#>  9  62.7  26.5  61.0  88.9  239.
#> 10  65.2  23.1  25.5  51.0  165.
#> # … with 20 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

NOTE: if you are unfamiliar with `purrr`, you can also use something like `lapply`, etc.

You can read more about these types of more tricky `dplyr` operations (`!!`, `!!!`, etc.) here:

https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: This is great! The one thing I would add in case some people find it useful is that this works because `sum()` accepts `...` as input. Some functions accept a vector (e.g. `entropy::entropy()`), in which case you can simply use `c()` to wrap the unpacking structure: `some_function(c(!!!map(cols, as.name)), other.args = blah)`

Answer (score 2):

A few approaches I've taken in the past:

- use a pre-existing row-wise function (e.g. `rowSums`)
- using `reduce` (which doesn't apply to all functions)
- complicated transposing
- custom function with `pmap`

### Using pre-existing row-wise functions

```r
set.seed(1)
df_1 <- data.frame(
  x = replicate(4, runif(30, 20, 100)), 
  y = sample(1:3, 30, replace = TRUE)
)

library(tidyverse)

# rowSums
df_1 %>%
  mutate(var = rowSums(select(., -y))) %>%
  head()
#>        x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4 y      var
#> 1 41.24069 58.56641 93.03007 39.17035 3 232.0075
#> 2 49.76991 67.96527 43.48827 24.71475 2 185.9382
#> 3 65.82827 59.48330 56.72526 71.38306 2 253.4199
#> 4 92.65662 34.89741 46.59157 90.10154 1 264.2471
#> 5 36.13455 86.18987 72.06964 82.31317 3 276.7072
#> 6 91.87117 73.47734 40.64134 83.78471 2 289.7746
```

### Using Reduce

```r
df_1 %>%
  mutate(var = reduce(select(., -y),`+`))  %>%
  head()
#>        x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4 y      var
#> 1 41.24069 58.56641 93.03007 39.17035 3 232.0075
#> 2 49.76991 67.96527 43.48827 24.71475 2 185.9382
#> 3 65.82827 59.48330 56.72526 71.38306 2 253.4199
#> 4 92.65662 34.89741 46.59157 90.10154 1 264.2471
#> 5 36.13455 86.18987 72.06964 82.31317 3 276.7072
#> 6 91.87117 73.47734 40.64134 83.78471 2 289.7746
```

### ugly transposing and matrix / data.frame conversion

```r
df_1 %>%
  mutate(var = select(., -y) %>% as.matrix %>% t %>% as.data.frame %>% map_dbl(var)) %>%
  head()
#>        x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4 y       var
#> 1 41.24069 58.56641 93.03007 39.17035 3 620.95228
#> 2 49.76991 67.96527 43.48827 24.71475 2 318.37221
#> 3 65.82827 59.48330 56.72526 71.38306 2  43.17011
#> 4 92.65662 34.89741 46.59157 90.10154 1 878.50087
#> 5 36.13455 86.18987 72.06964 82.31317 3 520.72241
#> 6 91.87117 73.47734 40.64134 83.78471 2 506.16785
```

### Custom function with `pmap`

```r
my_var <- function(...){
  vec <-  c(...)
  var(vec)
}

df_1 %>%
  mutate(var = select(., -y) %>% pmap(my_var)) %>%
  head()
#>        x.1      x.2      x.3      x.4 y      var
#> 1 41.24069 58.56641 93.03007 39.17035 3 620.9523
#> 2 49.76991 67.96527 43.48827 24.71475 2 318.3722
#> 3 65.82827 59.48330 56.72526 71.38306 2 43.17011
#> 4 92.65662 34.89741 46.59157 90.10154 1 878.5009
#> 5 36.13455 86.18987 72.06964 82.31317 3 520.7224
#> 6 91.87117 73.47734 40.64134 83.78471 2 506.1679
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Instead `+`, I can put `mean`,  `var` (answer with `reduce`)? How can I do this?

Comment: I've updated it with `var`, using a different strategy. It's not particularly elegant (I'm assuming there's some row-wise custom functions for many things), but this approach would generally work as long as all columns `-y` are of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem since dplyr operates column-wise for many operations. I originally used `apply` from base R to apply over rows, but `apply` is [problematic when handling character and numeric types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15618527/why-does-as-matrix-add-extra-spaces-when-converting-numeric-to-character).

Instead we can use (the aging) **plyr** and [`adply`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/adply) to do this simply, since plyr lets us treat a one-row data frame as a vector:

```
df_1 %>% select(-y) %>% adply(1, function(df) c(v1 = sd(df[1, ])))
```

Note some functions like `var` won't work on a one-row data frame so we need to convert to vector using `as.numeric`.